# Avoid URL begin cached in the browser

Tags: html, caching, browser

I want to avoid an URL being cached in the browsers temporary files.

For example, I have an URL (http://www.phy.mtu.edu/basiccomputing/sample.html) that is opened in an iframe. I don't want this html file to be stored in the browsers cache.

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 5):

You can do this in many ways depending on what you're trying to achieve.

You can easily do this by adding uniqueness to the url for the iframe.

Ex. if you're setting the iframe using javascript you can set the src to

```
var date = new Date();
iframe.src = 'http://www.phy.mtu.edu/basiccomputing/sample.html?datetime=' + date.getTime();
```

If you have control over the sample.html page you can set

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
```

You can also set the cache-control, last-modified and etag headers to make the browser revalidate the page every time but this is a bit tricky to do... or at least get to work across all browsers :).

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about a plain old HTML page as your example says, you can insert a `META` tag in your head element.

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
```

See this [link](http://www.i18nguy.com/markup/metatags.html) for more information.

For an ASPX page, the cache can be controlled through the [HttpResponse.Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.cache%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) property.